# How to add numbers in a 'clock-like' way?

Tags: javascript

I am currently working with hours as numbers, such as `2230` being equivalent to 22:30. I would like to be able to add numbers to it and sum as if they were minutes added to hours

```
2030 + 60 = 2130 //and not 2090
2330 + 120 = 0230 //and not 2350
```

Is there a library or function to doing this? Or perhaps I should change the way I am handling hours?

Comment: If you are attempting to sum units of time, and they represent different unit measures, then it should be expected that you have to convert them to the same unit of measure before performing a summation.

Comment: *"`2330 + 120 = 0230 //and not 2350`"* Er, that would be `2450`, not `2650`, so it wraps around to `50` (since numbers don't have leading spaces, that's a presentation concept).

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend doing this, but if you want to do it, you have to handle the fact that you're pretending an hour is 100 minutes. You do that by extracting the real hours and minutes from the fake value, doing the math on them, and then reassembling them, something along these lines:

```
function toHoursAndMinutes(value) {
    // Get hours: `value` divided by 100
    const hours = Math.floor(value / 100);
    // Get minutes: the remainder of dividing by 100
    const minutes = value % 100;
    // Return them
    return [hours, minutes];
}

function fromHoursAndMinutes(hours, minutes) {
    // Reassemble the number where hours are worth 100
    return hours * 100 + minutes;
}

function add(a, b) {
    // Get `a`'s hours and minutes
    const [ahours, aminutes] = toHoursAndMinutes(a);
    // Get `b`'s
    const [bhours, bminutes] = toHoursAndMinutes(b);
    // Add the hours together, plus any from adding the minutes
    const hours = ahours + bhours + Math.floor((aminutes + bminutes) / 60);
    // Add the minutes together, ignoring extra hours
    const minutes = (aminutes + bminutes) % 60;
    // Reassemble
    return fromHoursAndMinutes(hours, minutes);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function toHoursAndMinutes(value) {
    // Get hours: `value` divided by 100
    const hours = Math.floor(value / 100);
    // Get minutes: the remainder of dividing by 100
    const minutes = value % 100;
    // Return them
    return [hours, minutes];
}

function fromHoursAndMinutes(hours, minutes) {
    // Reassemble the number where hours are worth 100
    return hours * 100 + minutes;
}

function add(a, b) {
    // Get `a`'s hours and minutes
    const [ahours, aminutes] = toHoursAndMinutes(a);
    // Get `b`'s
    const [bhours, bminutes] = toHoursAndMinutes(b);
    // Add the hours together, plus any from adding the minutes
    // The % 24 wraps around
    const hours = (ahours + bhours + Math.floor((aminutes + bminutes) / 60)) % 24;
    // Add the minutes together, ignoring extra hours
    const minutes = (aminutes + bminutes) % 60;
    // Reassemble
    return fromHoursAndMinutes(hours, minutes);
}

console.log(add(2030, 60));
console.log(add(2330, 120));
```

**But again**, I don't recommend this. Instead, work with time values (`Date` or just milliseconds-since-the-Epoch, etc.) and convert for display when you need to display it.

Note that `50` rather than `0250`, for two reasons: 1. `2330` + `120` is `2450` which is `00:50`, not `02:50`, and numbers don't have leading spaces except in *string* representations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my implementation of it

```js
function add(current, time) {
    const hours = Math.floor(time / 60);
    const minutes = time % 60;
    const currentMinutes = parseInt(current.toString().slice(2));
    const currentHours = parseInt(current.toString().slice(0, 2));
    const newMinutes = (currentMinutes + minutes) % 60;
    const additionalHours = (currentMinutes + minutes) > 60 ? 1 : 0;
    const newHours = (currentHours + hours + additionalHours) % 24;


    return `${newHours < 10 ? '0' : ''}${newHours}${newMinutes < 10 ? '0' : ''}${newMinutes}`;
}

console.log(add(2030, 60)); // 2130
console.log(add(2330, 120)); // 0130
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the working code for your clock.

```
var nowTime = '2350'; //current time in String..
var newMin = 120; // min you want to add in int..
var tMinutes = parseInt(nowTime.toString().slice(2)); //taking out the min
var tHours = parseInt(nowTime.toString().slice(0, 2)); //taking out the hr
var newMinutes = (newMin + tMinutes) % 60;
var newHr = tHours + parseInt(((newMin + tMinutes) / 60));
var newTime =  `${newHr >= 24 ? newHr-24 : newHr}${newMinutes}`;
newTime = newTime.length < 4 ? '0'+newTime : newTime;
console.log(newTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle date math, a library is probably best, because *date math is hard*, and the source of so many bugs if done wrong. Now, knowing how to do date math is a great thing to learn though, and reading through the source code of date math libraries is a good way to do that. [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/math.html#duration-math) is a good library with duration objects that can do what you need easily, and has readable source code. Other duration libraries also exist, so take a look at a few of those and see what you like the best. You can also abuse he built-in Date library to act like  a duration object, but I don't think that's worth it.

But libraries aside, let's analyze the problem and what you might want to consider in solving it.

First off, I would say your first problem is trying to use a data type that isn't designed for what you want. A single integer is not a good idea for representing two values with different units. That is sort of what T.J. meant when he said it's a presentation concept. You have one object, but it's not really an integer in behavior. And date is close, but not quite right. So let's make a class. Duration seems like a good name:

```js
class Duration { … }
```

We know it has two parts, hours and minutes. Also, it seems a good idea to just use one unit and convert them. (You wouldn't have to, but it actually makes the math easier if you do the conversion):

```js
class Duration {
  constructor ({hours = 0, minutes = 0}) {
    this.totalMinutes = hours * 60 + minutes
  }
}
```

Now lets make some getters to get just the minutes section and the hours section:

```js
class Duration {
  …
  // just minutes that don't fit in hours
  get minutes () { return this.totalMinutes % 60 }
  get hours () { return Math.floor(this.totalMinutes / 60) }

  // and also let's present it as the string you wanted:
  asDisplayString() { return `${this.hours*100 + this.minutes}` }
}
```

Now we need to add them together. Some languages would let you use `+` for this, but javascript has limits on what we can make `+` do, so we'll add our own method. Note that because of how our constructor works, we can have more than 60 minutes  when we initialize the values. Is this a good idea? Maybe. Depends on how you want the object to behave. (While we'll go with it for this example, there are definite arguments against it, mostly because it is a bit confusing that `get minutes` doesn't return over 60 - but it's also makes a certain sense at the same time).

```js
class Duration {
  …
  add (otherDuration) {
    return new Duration({minutes: this.totalMinutes + otherDuration.totalMinutes})
  }
}
```

And now we can add our duration objects together, and the math is taken care of for us.

```js
class Duration {
  constructor ({hours = 0, minutes = 0}) {
    this.totalMinutes = hours * 60 + minutes
  }

  // just minutes that don't fit in hours
  get minutes () { return this.totalMinutes % 60 }
  get hours () { return Math.floor(this.totalMinutes / 60) }
  
  // and also let's present it as the string you wanted:
  asDisplayString() { return `${this.hours*100 + this.minutes}` }

  add (otherDuration) {
    return new Duration({minutes: this.totalMinutes + otherDuration.totalMinutes})
  }
}

d1 = new Duration({hours:20, minutes: 30})
d2 = new Duration({minutes: 50})
console.log(d1.asDisplayString(), '+', d2.asDisplayString(), '=', d1.add(d2).asDisplayString())
```